# PPTP VPN in ubuntu cannot connect

Tags: vpn, pptp

I use ubuntu 14.04,Today when I connect to my pptp vpn,it failed;And I do not know how to do it.
I see the following messages in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Apr 14 12:20:29 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' disappeared
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 5149
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: init (1)
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]: <info> VPN connection 'VPN 连接 2' (Connect) reply received.
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[5153]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[5153]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[5153]: Using interface ppp0
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[5153]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/15
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[5159]: nm-pptp-service-5149 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[5171]: nm-pptp-service-5149 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[5171]: nm-pptp-service-5149 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Apr 14 12:20:45 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[5171]: nm-pptp-service-5149 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
Apr 14 12:20:46 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[5171]: nm-pptp-service-5149 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Apr 14 12:20:46 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[5171]: nm-pptp-service-5149 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Apr 14 12:20:46 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[5171]: nm-pptp-service-5149 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 53504).
Apr 14 12:20:49 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu kernel: [ 5657.862831] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=dc:0e:a1:e2:13:94:28:2c:b2:fc:fd:73:08:00 SRC=199.101.117.111 DST=192.168.2.120 LEN=46 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=13330 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 12:20:49 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu kernel: [ 5657.862881] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=dc:0e:a1:e2:13:94:28:2c:b2:fc:fd:73:08:00 SRC=199.101.117.111 DST=192.168.2.120 LEN=42 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=13331 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 12:20:49 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu kernel: [ 5657.963781] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=dc:0e:a1:e2:13:94:28:2c:b2:fc:fd:73:08:00 SRC=199.101.117.111 DST=192.168.2.120 LEN=59 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=13332 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 12:21:10 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu kernel: [ 5678.873164] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=dc:0e:a1:e2:13:94:28:2c:b2:fc:fd:73:08:00 SRC=199.101.117.111 DST=192.168.2.120 LEN=46 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=13345 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[5153]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[5153]: Connection terminated.
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[5159]: nm-pptp-service-5149 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:204]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[5159]: nm-pptp-service-5149 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:216]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[5153]: Modem hangup
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[5171]: nm-pptp-service-5149 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:234]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[5171]: nm-pptp-service-5149 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[5171]: nm-pptp-service-5149 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[5153]: Exit.
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]: <info> Policy set '自动以太网' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Apr 14 12:21:16 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[888]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Apr 14 12:21:18 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu kernel: [ 5686.892463] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:68:5b:35:81:3d:a1:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.22 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=4346 PROTO=2 
Apr 14 12:21:19 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu kernel: [ 5687.821489] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:68:5b:35:7b:6c:04:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.139 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=28029 PROTO=2
```

After google it,I have installed network-manager-pptp and network-manager-vpnc.
It worked in android and win8.1,but just failed in ubuntu.
Here are some my vpn config:(I cannot upload images)
1.I filled out the VPN gateway, username, password
2.In Advanced Configuration,I checked MPPE and removed PAP,CHAP,EAP

can anyone help me?
Or need some more details?

#### Edit one

after doing `sudo ufw allow proto udp from 199.101.117.111 port 47 to 192.168.2.120 port 47`
 it seems not working.The fllowing is the updated info:

```
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 4423
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]: <info> VPN connection 'VPN 连接 2' (Connect) reply received.
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[4427]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[4427]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[4427]: Using interface ppp0
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[4427]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/0
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[4431]: nm-pptp-service-4423 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[4445]: nm-pptp-service-4423 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[4445]: nm-pptp-service-4423 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Apr 14 15:11:34 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[4445]: nm-pptp-service-4423 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
Apr 14 15:11:35 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[4445]: nm-pptp-service-4423 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Apr 14 15:11:35 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[4445]: nm-pptp-service-4423 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Apr 14 15:11:35 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[4445]: nm-pptp-service-4423 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 55680).
Apr 14 15:11:35 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu kernel: [ 1229.669311] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=dc:0e:a1:e2:13:94:28:2c:b2:fc:fd:73:08:00 SRC=199.101.117.111 DST=192.168.2.120 LEN=59 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=38683 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 15:11:37 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu kernel: [ 1231.530488] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=dc:0e:a1:e2:13:94:28:2c:b2:fc:fd:73:08:00 SRC=199.101.117.111 DST=192.168.2.120 LEN=46 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=38684 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 15:11:51 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu dbus[781]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' (using servicehelper)
Apr 14 15:11:51 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu dbus[781]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Apr 14 15:11:51 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu kernel: [ 1246.012237] systemd-hostnamed[4456]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
Apr 14 15:11:54 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu ntfs-3g[4466]: Version 2013.1.13AR.1 external FUSE 29
Apr 14 15:11:54 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu ntfs-3g[4466]: Mounted /dev/sdb8 (Read-Write, label "", NTFS 3.1)
Apr 14 15:11:54 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu ntfs-3g[4466]: Cmdline options: rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177
Apr 14 15:11:54 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu ntfs-3g[4466]: Mount options: rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,default_permissions,fsname=/dev/sdb8,blkdev,blksize=4096
Apr 14 15:11:54 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu ntfs-3g[4466]: Global ownership and permissions enforced, configuration type 7
Apr 14 15:11:54 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu udisksd[2762]: Mounted /dev/sdb8 at /media/zerolu/00085E86000034F91 on behalf of uid 1000
Apr 14 15:11:56 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu ntfs-3g[4472]: Version 2013.1.13AR.1 external FUSE 29
Apr 14 15:11:56 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu ntfs-3g[4472]: Mounted /dev/sdb7 (Read-Write, label "", NTFS 3.1)
Apr 14 15:11:56 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu ntfs-3g[4472]: Cmdline options: rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177
Apr 14 15:11:56 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu ntfs-3g[4472]: Mount options: rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,default_permissions,fsname=/dev/sdb7,blkdev,blksize=4096
Apr 14 15:11:56 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu ntfs-3g[4472]: Global ownership and permissions enforced, configuration type 7
Apr 14 15:11:56 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu udisksd[2762]: Mounted /dev/sdb7 at /media/zerolu/000538A60008D56E1 on behalf of uid 1000
Apr 14 15:11:56 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu kernel: [ 1250.597804] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=dc:0e:a1:e2:13:94:28:2c:b2:fc:fd:73:08:00 SRC=199.101.117.111 DST=192.168.2.120 LEN=46 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=38697 PROTO=47 
Apr 14 15:11:58 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu ntfs-3g[4477]: Version 2013.1.13AR.1 external FUSE 29
Apr 14 15:11:58 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu ntfs-3g[4477]: Mounted /dev/sdb9 (Read-Write, label "", NTFS 3.1)
Apr 14 15:11:58 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu ntfs-3g[4477]: Cmdline options: rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177
Apr 14 15:11:58 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu ntfs-3g[4477]: Mount options: rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,default_permissions,fsname=/dev/sdb9,blkdev,blksize=4096
Apr 14 15:11:58 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu ntfs-3g[4477]: Global ownership and permissions enforced, configuration type 7
Apr 14 15:11:58 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu udisksd[2762]: Mounted /dev/sdb9 at /media/zerolu/0000A4090008A876 on behalf of uid 1000
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[4427]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[4427]: Connection terminated.
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[4427]: Modem hangup
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[4431]: nm-pptp-service-4423 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:204]: short read (-1): Input/output error
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[4431]: nm-pptp-service-4423 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:216]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[4445]: nm-pptp-service-4423 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:234]: Closing connection (unhandled)
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[4445]: nm-pptp-service-4423 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pptp[4445]: nm-pptp-service-4423 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu pppd[4427]: Exit.
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]: <info> Policy set '自动以太网' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Apr 14 15:12:05 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Apr 14 15:12:10 Lenovo-G470-ubuntu NetworkManager[866]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' disappeared
```

#### Edit two

I have solved it by resotring my system and it works.

Comment: If I have some wrong things in my asks please tell me,thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on output allow traffic from vpn server to your pc on `port 47`.

`PPTP` user `gre (Generic Routing Encapsulation)` protocol. This protocol uses vpn server and send `udp` packets to your pc on `port 47`. Without this protocol `pptp` connection is not possible.

```
sudo ufw allow proto udp from 199.101.117.111 port 47 to 192.168.2.120 port 47
```

This is first step, and based on result and `vpn server` configuration we can discuss about `mppe`, `chap`, `pap` ....

**Edit One**

Because you don't have working solution with my first answer try to allow all trafic from vpn server

```
sudo ufw allow vpn_server_address
```

If still you can not connect, maybe is problem in `nm-pptp-pppd-plugin`.

Try with this script

Create file with some name and put in

```
nano name_of_script
```

script

```
#!/bin/bash
function routeadd {
    route add -host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev ppp0
    route add -net xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx dev ppp0
}
function makepptp {
   echo pty \"pptp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --nolaunchpppd\" >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo remotename PPTP >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo require-mppe-128 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo file /etc/ppp/options.pptp >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
   echo ipparam vpn >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
pppd call vpn &
}
if [ -a /etc/ppp/chap-secrets ];
        then
        rm /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
    echo $1 PPTP $2 '*' >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets;
else
    echo $1 PPTP $2 '*' >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets;
fi

if [ -e /etc/ppp/peers/vpn ];
    then
    rm /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    echo name $1 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    makepptp;
    sleep 8;
    routeadd;
else
    echo name $1 >> /etc/ppp/peers/vpn;
    makepptp;
    sleep 8;
    routeadd;
fi
```

In script change you host ip and add network or/and host witch you wish to connect via vpn

Usage:

```
sudo /path_to_script/name_of_script username password
```

**note**: set execute permision to script

Comment: Firstly，Thanks for your answer，I have tried your way,and it seems not works,what else do you need

Comment: I add `edit one` in answer. Try.

Comment: Sorry for replying to you late.I have solved my problem but without your way.Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @zerolu how did you solve it?

Comment: restore ubuntu system